# R how to turn all data in a column to a single string?

Tags: r

I have a tibble `df`, and if I do the below, I get all rows data in below format.

```
df = tibble(A1=c("A03816","A03817"))
> df[["A1"]]
[1] "A03816" "A03817"
```

But I want those 2 words in the same string like below, how can I do it?

```
[1] "A03816 A03817"
```

Comment: You could use `paste(df[["A1"]], collapse = " ")`

Comment: this is good answer, you should post it as answer Martin, it's exactly what I want